# How to get ema value at position entry?

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to get the 50 EMA value when a buy order is placed. Here is come basic code I put together if you need it.

```
strategy("MACD Strategy", overlay=true, initial_capital = 500000, default_qty_value = 500000, 

default_qty_type = strategy.cash)
fastLength = input(12)
slowlength = input(26)
MACDLength = input(9)

len1 = input.int(50, minval=50, title="Length of 50")
src1 = input(close,title="Source")
out1 = ta.ema(src1, len1)
plot(out1, title="EMA", color=color.blue)

MACD = ta.ema(close, fastLength) - ta.ema(close, slowlength)
aMACD = ta.ema(MACD, MACDLength)
delta = MACD - aMACD
if (ta.crossover(delta, 0))
    strategy.entry("MacdLE", strategy.long, comment="MacdLE")
if (ta.crossunder(delta, 0))
    strategy.entry("MacdSE", strategy.short, comment="MacdSE")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=5
strategy("MACD Strategy", overlay=true, initial_capital = 500000, default_qty_value = 500000, default_qty_type = strategy.cash)

fastLength = input(12)
slowlength = input(26)
MACDLength = input(9)

len1 = input.int(50, minval=50, title="Length of 50")
src1 = input(close,title="Source")
out1 = ta.ema(src1, len1)
plot(out1, title="EMA", color=color.blue)

MACD = ta.ema(close, fastLength) - ta.ema(close, slowlength)
aMACD = ta.ema(MACD, MACDLength)
delta = MACD - aMACD

if (ta.crossover(delta, 0))
    strategy.entry("MacdLE", strategy.long, comment="MacdLE: "+ str.tostring(close))
if (ta.crossunder(delta, 0))
    strategy.entry("MacdSE", strategy.short, comment="MacdSE: "+ str.tostring(close))
```